# Modify empty values in array

Tags: php, arrays

I want modify null values in an array(). I only want to modify, not to clean them.

```
$arr = array ( 'a' => '', 'b' => 'Apple', 'C' => 'Banana');
```

I want modify and obtain this:

```
array(a => 'N', b => Apple, C => 'Banana');
```

I try array_walk() and array_filter(). But empty values are removed.

And I obtain :

```
array('b' => 'Apple', 'C' => 'Banana');
```

Comment: show your `array_walk` attempt...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array_walk($arr, function(&$val)
{
    if($val == null)
    {
        $val = 'N';
    }
});
```

This code works perfectly fine on my machine.

Comment: and you might also want to add ( || $val == '' )

Comment: I think OP meant empty instead of null given his example.

Comment: `''` in PHP is considered as NULL (of course if we don't compare types), but there is no problem in changing that.

Comment: Ok works fine with `NULL` but not with `''`. o_O I'm going to look more closely.

Comment: @zourite, if you are using `$val === null` the interpreter will also check type of the $val (so it has to be "real" `NULL`). And as @Alex said, you can also use `if(empty($val))`.

Comment: Ok but initially I had written the same code but with `''` and I didn't understand why not working.

Comment: Strage, because when I replace `== null` with `== ''` I get same result.

Comment: @Glibnes The (==) operator compares "equality", not if they are "identical". In this case, `(string) ''` and `(void) null` are "equal", they are both `empty()` but not (===) "identical". It depends the comparison you are doing and the context, that's why PHP have an `empty()` function to avoid you that hassle.

Comment: I meant @zourite. But I'm glad you are offended.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this:

```
$arr = array ( 'a' => '', 'b' => 'Apple', 'C' => 'Banana' );

foreach ( $arr as $key => $value ) {
    if ( !$value ) $value = 'N';
    $new_arr[ $key ] = $value;
}

print_r( $new_arr );
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => N
    [b] => Apple
    [C] => Banana
)
```

Comment: Why don't you use reference like this: `foreach($arr as &$value)`?

Comment: Why you need that? When you use reference, you don't need `$key` to change the original array, because simple `$value = 'N';` will do that.

Comment: I'm not changing the original here, but creating a new one ;)

Comment: Aww right. OP asked for modifying original array, so that why I was asking these questions :)

Comment: It's better to keep the original somewhere and use a new modified. That way you can always go back to the original values if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($yourArray as $k=>&$v) {
    if (empty($v)) {
        $v = 'N';
    }
}
```